# Why is the last instantiated object end up first in ScrollView table

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just do not get this problem, why is the record that is being the last to be instantiated end up as the first record in the scrollView but last, as it should be, in the print?

I have been spending a lot of time testing and trying to understand what the problem is but I am not able to find it.

Here is a condensed print from (_xxx += "END";):

```
====== STARTGRUPP 1 - STARTID: 08:45 ======
Yasmin Carlsson 
Karl Wallin 
Åsa Jansson 
Lars Lindberg 
====== STARTGRUPP 2 - STARTID: 08:55 ======
Mikael Yngvesson 
Lars Svensson 
Carina Eriksson 
Sara Ivarsson 

…

====== STARTGRUPP 12 - STARTID: 10:35 ======
Maria Källviks Buggy
Wilma Wallin Buggy
Tove Berg Buggy
Peter Jansson Buggy
====== STARTGRUPP 13 - STARTID: 10:45 ======
Jan Mårtensson Buggy
Gustav Jansson Buggy

END
```

Here is the result in the actual scrollView:

[image]

The record with the name "Gustav Jansson Buggy", which is processed last is now displayed first.

Here is the code snippet I am currently testing:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < _totNrRecords; i++)
    {
        for (int g = 0; g < group_List.Count; g++)
        {
            if (group_List[g].index == _nrIx)
            {
                // _xxx += group_List[g].index + ") " + group_List[g].text + "\n";
                _nrIx++;
                groupPlayerObj = img_GroupSVgo;
                groupPlayerObj = Instantiate(groupPlayerObj);
                groupPlayerObj.transform.SetParent(CONTENT.transform, false);
                groupPlayerObj.GetComponentInChildren<TMP_Text>().text = group_List[g].text;
                _xxx += group_List[g].text + "\n";
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int p = 0; p < playerSV_List.Count; p++)
        {
            if (playerSV_List[p].index == 0) print("INDEX: " + playerSV_List[p].txt_PlayerName + " > " + playerSV_List[p].txt_PlayerBuggy);

            if (playerSV_List[p].index == _nrIx)
            {
                // _xxx += playerSV_List[p].index + ") " + playerSV_List[p].txt_PlayerName + " " + playerSV_List[p].txt_PlayerBuggy + "\n";
                _nrIx++;

                GameObject playerObjX = new GameObject();
                playerObj = playerObjX;
                Destroy(playerObjX);
                playerObj = img_PlayerSVgo;

                txt_PlayerName = playerObj.transform.Find("txt_PlayerNameSV").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
                txt_PlayerHcp = playerObj.transform.Find("txt_PlayerHcpSV").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
                txt_PlayerTee = playerObj.transform.Find("txt_PlayerTeeSV").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
                txt_PlayerBuggy = playerObj.transform.Find("txt_PlayerBuggySV").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();

                playerObj = Instantiate(playerObj);
                playerObj.transform.SetParent(CONTENT.transform, false);
                playerObj.name = playerSV_List[p].txt_PlayerName;
                _xxx += playerSV_List[p].txt_PlayerName + " " + playerSV_List[p].txt_PlayerBuggy + "\n";

                txt_PlayerName.text = playerSV_List[p].txt_PlayerName;
                txt_PlayerHcp.text = playerSV_List[p].txt_PlayerHcp;
                txt_PlayerTee.text = playerSV_List[p].txt_PlayerTee;
                txt_PlayerBuggy.text = playerSV_List[p].txt_PlayerBuggy;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    _xxx += "END";

    print(_xxx);
```